# Batch update using Entity Framework extended

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-extended

```
var IDsToUpdate = db.Orders.Where(x => listOfIDs.Contains(x.ID));

db.Orders.Update(IDsToUpdate , x => new Order{ OrderState = "TEST STATE" });
```

This is producing the runtime error:

> The query must be of type ObjectQuery or DbQuery.\r\nParameter name: source

I'm using EF 6.0 and EF Extended 6.0 and .NET 4

I need to do a batch/bulk update as performance is not acceptable otherwise.

`listOfIDs` is of type `List<string>`

Comment: Can you include the `Update` function in the question please?

Comment: the Update function documentation is here:
https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/blob/master/readme.md

Comment: @neoswarm Did you get any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You run the update on the query itself.

```
db.Orders
.Where(x => listOfIDs.Contains(x.ID))
.Update(x => new Order{ OrderState = "TEST STATE" });
```